# php header function redirects only the localhost user not the signed up users

Tags: php

I am making a `login/register` system.
Everything works fine except the `header function.`
When i try to login with a user that i signed up through the register form the `function` wont work...but when i login with the `localhost` user it it works and redirects to the next page.
The `session_start` `function` is included with a `connect.php` file that i have included.

```
include("connect.php");

$error = "";
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

     if(email_exists($email,$con))
     {
         $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
         $retrievePassword=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

         if(md5($password)!==$retrievePassword['password'])
         {
             $error="Password is inccorect";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         $_SESSION['email']=$email;
         header("location: profile.php");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Outside linking to code is sort of frowned upon. You will need to post your script here using as minimal amount of code that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: Check the error log for a `Headers already sent` warning.

Comment: where to check that? I dont see any errors

Comment: Did you started `session` and  also exit after header. And make sure no output before header not even a space in connect.php or anywhere.

Comment: there is no other output before header and yes i have started the session its  in the connect.php file and i just tried the exit but nothing happened again

Comment: so when you register you user with register function are they saved in database and have you md5 the password before saving in database??

Comment: its making it into md5 before. When i open the browser and go to localhost/folder_of_file/login.php it has already filled the emain and password inputs with [localhost] and the password of root user.